# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a firestore database that looks like this.

[image]

I'm trying to make "stocks : 999" value change, so that it can be 998, 997, etc...

So I followed given instructions on firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_8), but I bump into an error when trying to make it work.

```
const [stock, SetStock] = useState([]);
const toUpdate = doc(db, "stocks", "stocks");

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(collection(db, "stocks"),(snapshot) => 
      SetStock(snapshot.docs[0].data().stocks)
     ),
 [] 
 );
 
 const update = () => {
   updateDoc(toUpdate, {
    stocks : increment(-1)
  });
  
 }
```

In here, the important things are `const toUpdate = doc(db, "stocks", "stocks")` and `const update = ()...`, the other are working great.

Anyways, after clicking the button that triggers "update", I get an error that says
[image]

Why ?

By the way, I am using React, I don't know if this might be useful.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.  (In particular, I'm talking about the error message - you should be able to copy that text here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to update a document with the path "/stocks/stocks".  The error message is telling you that document doesn't exist.  I'm inclined to agree, since the document you show in the screenshow has the path "/stocks/sL..G1" (redacted).  You will need to use the correct document ID to build a path to the document to update.